# dynamically add keys and values to hash and hash within hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of names

```
department = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
```

and an array of months

```
month = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'etc']
```

I need to dynamically merge these arrays into hashes to look like this:

```
h = {'name1' => {'jan' => '', 'feb' => '', 'mar' => '', 'etc' => ''},
'name2' => {'jan' => '', 'feb' => '', 'mar' => '', 'etc' => ''}, 'name3' => {'jan' => '', 'feb' => '', 'mar' => '', 'etc' => ''}}
```

How would I go about dynamically adding keys into my hash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
department
  .each_with_object({}) do |name, h|
     # taking an empty hash which will be holding your final output.
     h[name] = month.product([""]).to_h
   end
```

Read [`Array#product`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-product) to know how `month.product([""])` line is working. You can convert an array of array to hash using [`to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-to_h).

Comment: Interesting use of [`Array#product`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-product) here.

Comment: both you and @tadman have very enlightening answers, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

As is often the case the answer lies in the power of [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html):

```
Hash[
  department.map do |d|
    [
      d,
      Hash[
        month.map do |m|
          [ m, '' ]
        end
      ]
    ]
  end
]
```

There's a lot going on in here, but it boils down to a two part process, one converting the `department` list into a hash of hashes, and a second part to populate that with a converted `month` structure.

`Hash[]` is a handy way of converting key/value pairs into a proper Hash structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
department = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
month = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'etc']

month_hash = month.each_with_object({}) { |m, res| res[m] = '' }
result = department.each_with_object({}) { |name, res| res[name] = month_hash.dup }

p result
```

This way you could build month_hash, and then use it to build result hash, that you need

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it.

1) Make a Hash out of your months array

```
month_hash = Hash[month.map { |m| [m ,''] }]
```

2) Make a Hash out of your department array, inserting the newly made month hash.

```
result_hash = Hash[department.map { |d| [d, month_hash] }]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
month = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'etc']
department = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']

month_hash = month.map {|m| [m, '']}.to_h
p department.map {|d| [d, month_hash]}.to_h
```